# #if Macro in swift to checking device

Tags: swift

i am defining the macro at my Appdelegate , here is my code

```
let IPHONE = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
let IPAD = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
#if IPHONE
    let LEFT_DRAWER_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 270.0
    #elseif IPAD
let LEFT_DRAWER_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 404.0
    #else
let LEFT_DRAWER_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 404.0
    #endif
```

but it always returns LEFT_DRAWER_HEIGHT = 404.0 rather i have run in iphone device. whats the mistake? can anyone figure it out.

Comment: They are just variables and not macros. So, just use if statements and not #if

Comment: Also, Apple recommends moving away from user interface idioms and into size classes. Since the iPhone 6+ came out, the line between iPhone / iPad started to blur...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have separate targets for iPhone and iPad? And are you defining those constants in each of those targets?

`#if` is a compile time conditional, so if you have a universal app, the compiler can't know at compile time what device will the app run on. You should instead use a normal if condition.

Comment: yes i have an universal app . if i use normal if condition then i have to use at each VC for check device. for that what can i do ?

Comment: He means that you determine _at run time_ whether your app is running on an iPad or an iPhone, and choose the constant accordingly.